# What gets called when the screen changes orientation? My app is restarting when I change orientations

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I have built an app that is a simple question and answer game. A Question is displayed and you can select true or false, and then a toast appears to tell you if you got the question correct. You can then press a button to move to the next question. The problem is that when you rotate the screen (change the screens orientation) the app goes back to the first question displayed. What gets called to make this happen? I have three classes. The first is the MainActivity which launches the quiz layout. The next is a Question class. The last is the QuizActivity Class. Here is the code:

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.geoquiz;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    }
}
```

Question Class:

```
package com.example.geoquiz;

public class Question {
    private int mTextResId;
    private boolean mAnswerTrue;
    public Question(int textResId, boolean answerTrue) {
        mTextResId = textResId;
        mAnswerTrue = answerTrue;
    }
    public int getTextResId() {
        return mTextResId;
    }
    public void setTextResId(int textResId) {
        mTextResId = textResId;
    }
    public boolean isAnswerTrue() {
        return mAnswerTrue;
    }
    public void setAnswerTrue(boolean answerTrue) {
        mAnswerTrue = answerTrue;
    }
}
```

QuizActivity Class:

```
package com.example.geoquiz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private Button mNextButton;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;
    private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[] {
            new Question(R.string.question_australia, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_americas, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_asia, true),
    };
    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;
// ...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    mQuestionTextView = (TextView)    findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
    mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { checkAnswer(true); }
    });
    mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { checkAnswer(false); }
    });
    mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });
    updateQuestion();
}
    private void updateQuestion() {
        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
    }
    private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
        boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();
        int messageResId = 0;
        if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
            messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
        } else {
            messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

} // to close the entire class
```

I believe the code to update the question begins in the QuizActivity class. I think the issue is that the counter for which question to be displayed is being set back to 0, but I do not know where to set a breakpoint to check this. Whenever I set a breakpoint none of the UI is updated and I can therefore not test this.

I also have the XML file if you want to test this for yourself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="24dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/true_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/false_button" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/next_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/next_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that when you rotate the screen (change the screens orientation) the app goes back to the first question displayed. What gets called to make this happen?

Your activity is destroyed and recreated as part of a [configuration change](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes). Consider [using a `ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states) to hold your activity's state and be able to retain it across configuration changes.

Comment: Would the ViewModel be declared in its own separate class or can I just add one to QuizActivity?

Comment: @hippoman: It has to be a separate class, and you would need some code in your activity to use it. For example, [this class is a `ViewModel` implementation](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/tree/v0.3/ViewModel/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/samplerj/viewmodel) for holding a list of colors, and [this activity](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/blob/v0.3/ViewModel/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/samplerj/viewmodel/MainActivity.java) uses it to populate a `RecyclerView` to show the list of colors.

Comment: Google has promoted it's Android Jetpack for better development. In that you can find Android Architecture Components and ViewModels is one of them, for holding states. I would argue you to use them and follow this pattern, please don't save them in made-up classes or variables, this will in the end bite you. If you follow the correct architecture it will be easier to test and supported from the community and Google. Read more here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack

Answer (score 1):

You can use ViewModel or override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) and write the application state values you want to change to the Bundle parameter like as current question number and it will get passed in to onCreate() and also onRestoreInstanceState() where you would then extract the values.